# GCP: Cloud NAT: Why does a Regional IP address attached to a Cloud NAT get labelled as "unused"?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

If I set up Cloud NAT, and attach it to a network, I am charged about $0.050 per hour. This is fair since I don't have to set up my own NAT instance and I don't have to manage it myself.

Furthermore:

When reserving a static IP address on GCP, I am charged at a rate of about $0.010 per hour as long as I don't attach the IP address to an instance or a load balancer.

I understand that this is done to dissuade users from creating unused IP addresses.

However:

If I create a Regional IP address and instruct Cloud NAT to use that as its external IP address, the IP address is still marked as "unused" in the Cloud Console (`In use by: None` in the Web UI, and `RESERVED` using the `gcloud` command).

This leads to two things:

1. Confusion: It is not immediately obvious that the reserved IP address is in fact in use, and someone might try to delete it.
2. An unused IP address is charged, which is fair if it is indeed unused, but I would argue that it is in fact *not* unused, and google is running an "invisible instance" for me (even though it's just a network service feature in Andromeda, and probably does not involve a single running instance - at least according to the docs)

If anyone knows if this is a *feature* or a *bug*, I would be very thankful (and I would also be thankful if I could save $0.010 per hour :D)

## Update

From the billing console I can deduce that the static IP address is *not* being charged for (when attached to Cloud NAT), even though it is marked as "unused".

The question is now if the bug is with the Web UI/`gcloud` or the billing system.

Comment: I probably think $0.050 per hour is a bit expensive for  the small cluster I have. Price should scale with usage instead...

Comment: It might be an interesting test to see if you can indeed "accidentally" delete such an "unused" IP address deliberately.